# Files and folders added to a cloned repository are not seen in remote repository after pushing

Tags: github, push, commit

I have a problem with pushing to my remote repository.
What I did is:
1) I cloned an existing repository to my computer
2) I was working for a while at my computer with the project  (adding some folders with new data, doing some changes to the existing files)
3)
a) I created my own remote repository on GitHub
b) used `git remote set-url origin new.git.url/here`
c) used: `git add .` then `git commit -m "Comment"` then `git push`.
The outcome is that in my remote repository I have now only the files that were in the original cloned repository (if I made any changes to them, the changes are there), but no files or folders added by me are there.
When I commit files I added after pushing the repository for the first time, they are seen and commited.
Could you help me to push also all the changes I made to the project before pushing for the first time?
Edit: I think the problem lies in .gitgnore file, but I am not sure which lines I can delete and which not:

```
*.o
*.a
*.dSYM
*.csv
*.out
*.png
*.so
*.exe
*.dll
*.lib
*.dylib
mnist/
data/
caffe/
grasp/
images/
opencv/
convnet/
decaf/
submission/
cfg/
build/darknet/*
build_*/
!build/darknet/YoloWrapper.cs
.fuse*
*.weights
build/*.cmake
build/*.ninja
build/*.txt
build/*.json
build/CMakeFiles/
build/detect_cuda_compute_capabilities.cu
build/.ninja_deps
build/.ninja_log
build/Makefile

# OS Generated #
.DS_Store*
ehthumbs.db
Icon?
Thumbs.db
*.swp

# IDE generated #
.vs/
.vscode/

# Managed by CMake
src/version.h

# Build artifacts
lib/
share/
include/darknet/
uselib
uselib_track
darknet
```

This is link to the original repository: https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet

Comment: Can you try doing `git add --all` before committing?

Answer (score 0):

The right way in your case is to use [forks](https://help.github.com/en/github/getting-started-with-github/fork-a-repo).

So, the first step is to fork remote repository, than you can add changes to it, commit and push to your own fork.
You can't add changes and push it to the original repository if you are not the author of such repo, but you can do it with forks.

Comment: Thank you, @TiSer, but I don't want to push to the original repository, but to a new repository I created. It would be nice if I could push my local folder as it is now, because I don't remember exactly what changes I made so far to the original, copied repository.

Comment: @joanna29 What `$ git log` outputs? Can you see your commit "Comment" in the list?

Comment: @joanna29 Do you still need an answer on your question or could it be closed?